# How to separate the real and imaginary parts of a transfer function?

Tags: matlab, transfer-function

Here is a transfer function:

```
S = [tf([10 2 4],[1 95 2000 3450])];
```

How can I get `real(S)` and `Imag(S)`?

Comment: What output do you expect? Numeric data of symbolic expression?

Comment: I need symbolic form of (imag(S(s=jw))) or real (S(s=jw)) where w is frequency symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want the Fourier form of your transfer function. As far as I know, there's no builtin function for this so you'll need to use symbolic math:

```
num = [10 2 4];
den = [1 95 2000 3450];
syms s;
syms omega real; % Define as real-valued
f1 = poly2sym(num,s)/poly2sym(den,s)
f2 = subs(f1,s,1i*omega)
f2_real = simplify(real(f2))
f2_imag = simplify(imag(f2))
```

which returns

```
f1 =
 
(10*s^2 + 2*s + 4)/(s^3 + 95*s^2 + 2000*s + 3450)


f2 =
 
(- 10*omega^2 + omega*2i + 4)/(- omega^3*1i - 95*omega^2 + omega*2000i + 3450)


f2_real =
 
(4*(237*omega^4 - 7720*omega^2 + 3450))/(omega^6 + 5025*omega^4 + 3344500*omega^2 + 11902500)


f2_imag =
 
-(2*omega*(5*omega^4 - 9907*omega^2 + 550))/(omega^6 + 5025*omega^4 + 3344500*omega^2 + 11902500)
```

You can then use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) and `vpa`/`double` to evaluate these for a particular value of `omega`.

Comment: Alas, answers to more difficult questions get less upvotes